Unable to configure the bot in the microsoft teams
I am novice in the MS teams and bot development. I have created the project from the basic bot template and added the configure properties as guided here.
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.16/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.16",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "${{TEAMS_APP_ID}}",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Teams App, Inc.",
        "websiteUrl": "https://www.example.com",
        "privacyUrl": "https://www.example.com/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.example.com/termofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "color.png",
        "outline": "outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "MyProject${{APP_NAME_SUFFIX}}",
        "full": "full name for MyProject"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "short description for MyProject",
        "full": "full description for MyProject"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "${{BOT_ID}}",
            "scopes": [
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "isNotificationOnly": false,
            "configuration": {
                "groupChat": {
                    "fetchTask": true
                },
                "team": {
                    "fetchTask": true
                }
            },
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "configurableTabs": [],
    "staticTabs": [],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": []
}

When I try to run the project from the teams toolkit, it fails at teamsApp/validateManifest step
Summary:
1 failed.
You can check and update your Teams manifest at ./appPackage/manifest.json.
(×) Error: /bots/0 must NOT have additional properties

And this is because of configuration key. When I checked the JSON schema, there is no such key available in the object of bots array, but the schema in the documentation mentions otherwise.

The documentation seems outdated. I'm checking with the related teams for the replacement of "bots.configuration" and will get back to you as soon as possible. Sorry for the inconvenience.

You can track this Github issue for solutions. Thanks.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/teams-toolkit/issues/12200
